# Is there a lack of rigor in the standard analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, nonstandard-analysis

Does the difficulty of defining exactly what infinitesimals and differentials are denote a lack of rigor in standard real analysis?

For example, in an introductory course one may solve the differential equation such as $\frac{dy}{dx}=y$ by separation of variables by multiplying by $dx$ to obtain $\frac{dy}y=dx$ and integrating both sides, as if $dx$ and $dy$ were separate entities (infinitesimals) that can be manipulated algebraically (even though in the previous semester the students were typically taught that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is an indivisible symbol rather than a fraction).

Do we really need to define what a differential is to operate with it or can we understand it as an important operator in the study of calculus without it representing a gap in the theory? I've already read that non-standard analysis came to cover these gaps, but is it really necessary in this context? When I say necessary I mean necessary to establish the theory with a strong, well-established rigor and without any informality.

Comment: Calculus has been put on a rigorous foundation but not with infinitesimals. Instead they use limits to avoid them.

Comment: Standard analysis avoids the use of infinitesimal and infinitesimal quantities or numbers. It provides rigorous proofs but to avoid infinitesimals, the proofs require awkward logical arguments. Nonstandard analysis allows the proofs to be logically simpler.

Comment: We don't need infinitesimals to do calculus/analysis. The stuff that looks like infinitesimals in the notation are just notational tricks.

Comment: @Thomas, maybe *you* don't need infinitesimals to do calculus, but many *students* do in my experience.

Comment: @MikhailKatz That's bad teaching, then. Calculus is not about infinitesimals.

Comment: Certainly, it is not a flaw in a mathematical theory that some people don't understand it. Analysis is possible without infinitesimals, as taught.

Comment: @Thomas: "Calculus is not about infinitesimals":  You mean "Infinitesimal calculus is not about infinitesimals" - right?

Comment: @Thomas: "Analysis is possible without infinitesimals": Analysis is also possible without real numbers, and without rationals.  You can formulate everything in terms of the integers (it won't be simple).  So what does that prove?

Comment: Calculus can of course be rigoroulsy formulated without infinitesimals. I am glad that I leanrned it in the "standard" way and cannot agree at all that is simpler or more rigorous in the non-standard form.

Comment: I agree Thomas Andrews and CyclotomicField. I learnt it with limits and never had problems with this way to learn it. That there are other possibilities to approach it does not mean that they are better or easier or in any other sense superior to the standard analysis.

Comment: @Peter: the part about "limits" is a bit of a misconception.  Limits are present in both approaches.  In the infinitesimal approach, for example, the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ tends to zero would be the standard part of $f(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is infinitesimal.  The true dichotomy is therefore not between infinitesimals and limits but rather between infinitesimals and epsilon-delta definitions.  The traditional epsilon-delta definition of continuity, for example, has two quantifier alternations.  Educators tell us that a majority of students find this definition inaccessible.  ...

Comment: ...  On the other hand, Cauchy's definition of continuity using infinitesimals runs as follows: $f(x)$ is continuous if every infinitesimal increment $\alpha$ always produces an infinitesimal change $f(x+\alpha)-f(x)$ in the function.  Arguably (an also based on my own teaching experience) that's more accessible.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Epsilon-delta arguments can be a pain.  However, you don't make the job simpler by working with infinitesimals---in that setting, you have to build the hyperreal numbers, which is as much of a hurdle as epsilon-delta.  You trade one really abstract idea for another.  You don't lessen the pain, you just move it to another place.  Taking a non-standard approach also creates a bit of a hurdle when students advance to topology, in that you lose some of the metric intuition regarding open sets when you set aside epsilons and deltas.

Comment: So, while I entirely believe that one could teach an undergraduate real analysis course out of, say, Robinson's text (indeed, I thought about trying to design such a class when I was in graduate school), and that the class might be a great class, (1) I don't think that it is actually any *easier* than the standard approach, and (2) I worry about how it fits into the rest of the college mathematics curriculum.  I think that the promises of a non-standard approach being "easier" and "more intuitive" are overstated, at best.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Consider an analogy to your claim: "We don't need congruences to do number theory. The stuff that looks like congruences in the notations are just notational tricks.".  Would you agree to that too?

Comment: Congruences are a definition, not a thing that is added to our set of numbers. The model we have of the real line does not have infinitesimals - if you add them, then the real line becomes something different. Defining congruences is just notation - it doesn't add something o the theory of the integers. So is $dx$ in calculus. The real underlying meaning of $dx$ and $dy$ and the like, in analysis, are very subtle, but they are best seen as tangent vectors to a differentiable manifold. But we can think of them, in beginning calculus and the like, as behaving "like" infinitesimals, intuitively.

Comment: But adding infinitesimals as part of the real numbers causes a lot of problems, most related to the loss of the Archimedean property of the reals.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews But congruences naturally lead to ideal numbers, ideals, divisor theory, $p$-adics, etc. These new *concepts* (and "numbers") go a long way towards *simplifying* number theory, similar to how reification of infinitesimals simplifies calculus. An analogy of your above claim here would argue against these extensions of the integers. But such number system extensions have been extremely fruitful - leading to the development of much of algebra and number theory (Dedekind, Noether, Krull, etc).

Comment: Ideal numbers are not numbers, and when mathematicians realized what ideals are, they stopped calling them ideal numbers, because they are not numbers.

Comment: In any event, your question title asks about lack of rigor, not lack of clarity. Standard analysis without infinitesimals is quite well-known and rigorous. There is no lack of rigor. You want to add something not for rigor, but because it adds some intuitive clarity initially, without understanding the cost.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Kummer's ideal numbers are algebraic integers, so "numbers" (but that has little to do with my point).

Comment: Regarding lack of rigor when separating variables: with Eugene Wigner, I'd call this an "unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics" when all ODE solutions found with that unrigorous method miraculously solve the ODE by checking that afterwards. So why the headaches?

Comment: @XanderHenderson : Thanks for your comments.  My response was too long so I included it as part of my *answer* below.

Comment: @Thomas: You wrote "Ideal numbers are not numbers".  Did you mean this comment to apply to infinitesimals as well?

Answer (score 7):

This is a reasonable question though the choice of wording is not the best.  The shortcoming of traditional analysis as it was formalized 150 years ago is not a failure at the level of rigor (on the contrary, it was an improvement on that score as noted in the *comments*) but rather a failure to incorporate infinitesimals, which up to that point had been the bread and butter of the practice of analysis for several centuries.

In the 1960s, modern theories of infinitesimals were developed that meet modern standards of precision, but the residual effect of the notion that "infinitesimals are unrigorous" still lingers.

Several editors made some useful *comments* under the *question*.  My response is a bit too long to be included as a *comment* so I will include it here.  Xander mentioned the issue of the a comparison of epsilon-delta and infinitesimal approaches.  I would like to respond.  Xander wrote:

> "You trade one really abstract idea for another. You don't lessen the pain, you just move it to another place."

While I agree with Xander's description of the construction of the hyperreals as "abstract", I would also point out that in the basic infinitesimal calculus sequence, there is no more need to present a construction of the hyperreal line than a construction of the real line in the non-infinitesimal approaches (which is in practice not usually constructed at this level).  [Keisler's textbook](https://u.math.biu.ac.il/%7Ekatzmik/88-132.html) does a fine job explaining how to use the hyperreals in arguments; the construction itself can wait for a more advanced course.  I should also clarify that the idea is *not* to replace epsilon-delta definitions entirely by ones using infinitesimals, but rather to explain the key notions of the calculus such as derivative, continuity, and integral in terms of infinitesimals, as a first step.  Once the students understand these notions, they will have an easier time understanding the epsilon-delta paraphrases of these definitions.